# Angular/Typescript Losing Keys when converting object to array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, key-value

My code returns an object which is converted to an array but in the process the keys are converted to 0, 1, 2, 3 etc...

The original object has descriptive keys of url, id, name etc which I wish to retain.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I return an array that looks something like this?:

```
[
  "description": "blah blah blah"
  "telephone": "101",
  "id": "bedfordshire",
  "name": "Bedfordshire Police"
]
```

.ts code:

```
  fetchForceDetail(){
    return this.http
    .get<ForceDetail[]>('https://data.police.uk/api/forces/' + bedfordshire)
    .pipe(map(responseData => {
      const detailArray = [];
      for (const key in responseData) {
      if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key))
        detailArray.push(responseData[key])
      }
      return detailArray;
    }))
    .subscribe(forcedetails => {
      console.log(forcedetails);
  });
}
```

Comment: your array needs to have objects or primitives, not key-value pairs.

Comment: As Stavm said, your expected response is invalid. It looks like you want the original object as an array which doesn't work. My best guess would be something like an array of objects that have a key and a value property... But that is guess work at this point.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Object.keys and Object.values methods to convert object into array

```
let obj = {
  description: "blah blah blah"
  telephone: "101",
  id: "bedfordshire",
  name: "Bedfordshire Police"
}

let keys = Object.keys(obj); // ['description, 'telephone', 'id', 'name']

let values = Object.values(obj); //['blah blah blah', '101', 'bedfordshire', 'Bedfordshire Police']
```